# Iterative calculation in Abaqus by updating the plastic strain components?

Tags: python, abaqus

I want to perform several analyses successively in Abaqus, in each analysis - except the initial one - I should update the plastic strain components from the results calculated in the previous analysis (extracted from `.odb` files).
I Know how to initialize plastic strain components in the `.inp` file using the keyword: `*Initial Conditions, type=PLASTIC STRAIN`, for a simple analysis but I want to automate the process using python scripting.
Any ideas or help are highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Best regards,

Comment: Please add details of what have you tried and what did not work. The general answer for your quite general question will be "Open the odb --> extract results --> change plastic strain parameters in inp file --> relaunch --> repeat"

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Roman,
Sorry for the short explanation, I know how to extract the information needed from the previous analysis (from .odb file) at each analysis using python script and store them in an appropriate format, but I want to use that information extracted to update plastic strain components in the next analysis (update .inp file), I found *INCLUDE in the Abaqus documentation used to reference an external file containing a portion of the Abaqus input file, but I don't know what type of format should be used. and how to call them in the .inp file?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to use `* INCLUDE` key word, then save your part of the input file in some `my_external_file.inp` and add the line `*INCLUDE,INPUT=my_external_file.inp` to your main input file. If you already know how to extract data from an `odb` using Python then what is the problem? Open your input file (or `my_external_file.inp`) and modify it with Python using data extracted from odb.